# How to create a toggle menu in tkinter python?

Tags: python, tkinter, menu

Recently, I've made a calculator with tkinter. In that I want to create a toggle menu on the left hand side, but I don't know how to do so since I'm a newbie. Can anyone please help me to do this? please.

[this is a picture of my calculator, and the place marked with red color is where i want to add the toggle menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIJZi.png)

i have 2 images as one to open and one to close.

[this is the image for opening the toggle menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDlbQ.png)

[this is the image for closing the toggle menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFxf6.png)

[this is how i want the toggle menu bar to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSbu2.gif)

Below is the full code of my calculator. You can edit and send what i have to do. :)

```
import tkinter as tk

LABEL_COLOR = "#25265E"
DEFAULT_FONT_STYLE = ("Arial", 20,"bold")
OFF_WHITE = "#F8FAFF"


class Calculator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.window.geometry("375x660")
        self.window.resizable(height=True, width= True)
        self.window.title("Calculator")
        self.window.iconbitmap("c:/Users/sheran/Downloads/Calculator_Icon.ico")

        self.total_expression = ""
        self.current_expression = ""

        self.display_frame = self.create_display_frame()
         
        self.total_label, self.label =self.create_display_labels()

        self.digits = {
            7:(1,1), 8:(1,2), 9:(1,3),
            4:(2,1), 5:(2,2), 6:(2,3),
            1:(3,1), 2:(3,2), 3:(3,3),
            0:(4,2), ".":(4,1), 
        }

        self.operations = {"/": "\u00F7", "*": "\u00D7","-": "-", "+": "+"}
        self.buttons_frame = self.create_buttons_frame()

        

        self.buttons_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        for x in range(1,5):
            self.buttons_frame.rowconfigure(x, weight=1)
            self.buttons_frame.columnconfigure(x, weight=1)
        
       
        self.create_digit_buttons()
        self.create_operator_buttons()
        self.create_special_buttons()
        self.bind_keys()

        


    def bind_keys(self):
        self.window.bind("<Return>", lambda event: self.evaluate())
        self.window.bind("<BackSpace>", lambda event: self.delete())
        self.window.bind("<c>", lambda event: self.clear())

        for key in self.digits:
            self.window.bind(str(key), lambda event, digits = key: self.add_to_expressions(digits))

        for key in self.operations:
            self.window.bind(key, lambda event, operator = key: self.append_operator(operator))

        

    def create_special_buttons(self):
        self.create_clear_button()
        self.create_equals_button()
        self.create_delete_button()
        self.create_square_button()
        self.create_sqrt_button()

    def create_display_labels(self):
       total_label=tk.Label(self.display_frame, text= self.total_expression, anchor=tk.E, bg="#f5f5f5", fg="#25265E", padx=24, font=
                            ("Arial", 24))
       total_label.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

       label=tk.Label(self.display_frame, text= self.current_expression, anchor=tk.E, bg="#f5f5f5", fg="#25265E", padx=24, font=
                      ("Arial", 40, "bold"))
       label.pack(expand=True, fill="both")
            
       return total_label,label


    def create_display_frame(self):
        Frame = tk.Frame(self.window, height=221, bg="#f5f5f5")
        Frame.pack(expand=True, fill="both")
        return Frame
    
    def add_to_expressions(self, value):
        self.current_expression += str(value)
        self.update_label()

    def create_digit_buttons(self):
        def changedgt_on_hovering(event):
         
          event.widget['bg']='#F0F0F0'

        def returndgt_to_normalstate(event):
          
          event.widget['bg']='#fff'
        
        for digit,grid_value in self.digits.items():
            Button =  tk.Button(self.buttons_frame, text=str(digit), bg="#fff", fg="#25265E", font=("Arial", 24, "bold"), borderwidth=0,
                                activebackground="#f0f0f0",activeforeground="#111237",command=lambda x=digit: self.add_to_expressions(x))
            Button.grid(row=grid_value[0], column=grid_value[1], sticky=tk.NSEW)
            Button.bind("<Enter>", changedgt_on_hovering)
            Button.bind("<Leave>",returndgt_to_normalstate)

    def append_operator(self, operator):
        self.current_expression += operator
        self.total_expression += self.current_expression
        self.current_expression =""
        self.update_total_label()
        self.update_label()
    
 
    def create_operator_buttons(self):
        i = 0

        def changeop_on_hovering(event):
         
          event.widget['bg']='#E8EEFF'

        def returnop_to_normalstate(event):
          
          event.widget['bg']='#F8FAFF'

        for operator, symbol in self.operations.items():
            button = tk.Button(self.buttons_frame, text=symbol, bg= OFF_WHITE, fg= LABEL_COLOR, font= DEFAULT_FONT_STYLE, borderwidth=0,
                               activebackground="#e8eeff",activeforeground="#111237",command=lambda x=operator:self.append_operator(x))
            button.grid(row=i, column=4, sticky=tk.NSEW)
            button.bind("<Enter>", changeop_on_hovering)
            button.bind("<Leave>", returnop_to_normalstate)
            i += 1

    def clear(self):
        self.current_expression = ""
        self.total_expression = ""
        self.update_label()
        self.update_total_label()
        

    def create_clear_button(self):
        button = tk.Button(self.buttons_frame, text="C", bg= OFF_WHITE, fg= LABEL_COLOR, font= DEFAULT_FONT_STYLE, borderwidth=0,
                            activebackground="#e8eeff",activeforeground="#111237",command=self.clear)
        button.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.NSEW)
        
        def changecl_on_hovering(event):
          global create_clear_button
          button['bg']='#E8EEFF'
        
        def returncl_to_normalstate(event):
          global create_clear_button
          button['bg']= "#F8FAFF"
        
        button.bind("<Enter>", changecl_on_hovering)
        button.bind('<Leave>',returncl_to_normalstate)

    def delete(self):
    
      self.current_expression =  self.current_expression[:-1]
      self.update_label()

    def create_delete_button(self):
       
        button = tk.Button(self.buttons_frame, text="⌫", bg= "#fff", fg= "#25265E", font=("Arial", 20, "bold"), borderwidth=0,
                            activebackground="#fff",command=self.delete)
        button.grid(row=4, column=3,  sticky=tk.NSEW)

        def changedel_on_hovering(event):
          global create_delete_button
          button['bg']='#F0F0F0'
        
        def returndel_to_normalstate(event):
          global create_delete_button
          button['bg']='#fff'
        
        button.bind("<Enter>", changedel_on_hovering)
        button.bind('<Leave>',returndel_to_normalstate)
        



    def square(self):
        self.current_expression = str(eval(f"{self.current_expression}**2"))
        self.update_label()

    def create_square_button(self):
        button = tk.Button(self.buttons_frame, text="x\u00b2", bg= OFF_WHITE, fg= LABEL_COLOR, font= DEFAULT_FONT_STYLE, borderwidth=0,
                            activebackground="#e8eeff",activeforeground="#111237",command=self.square)
        button.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=tk.NSEW)
        
        
        def changesq_on_hovering(event):
          global create_square_button
          button['bg']='#E8EEFF'
        
        def returnsq_to_normalstate(event):
          global create_square_button
          button['bg']= "#F8FAFF"
        
        button.bind("<Enter>", changesq_on_hovering)
        button.bind('<Leave>',returnsq_to_normalstate)     
    
    def sqrt(self):
        self.current_expression = str(eval(f"{self.current_expression}**0.5"))
        self.update_label()

    def create_sqrt_button(self):
        button = tk.Button(self.buttons_frame, text="\u221ax", bg= OFF_WHITE, fg= LABEL_COLOR, font= DEFAULT_FONT_STYLE, borderwidth=0,
                            activebackground="#e8eeff",activeforeground="#111237",command=self.sqrt)
        button.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky=tk.NSEW)

        def changesqrt_on_hovering(event):
          global create_sqrt_button
          button['bg']='#E8EEFF'
        
        def returnsqrt_to_normalstate(event):
          global create_sqrt_button
          button['bg']= "#F8FAFF"
        
        button.bind("<Enter>", changesqrt_on_hovering)
        button.bind('<Leave>',returnsqrt_to_normalstate)

    def evaluate(self):
        self.total_expression += self.current_expression
        self.update_total_label()
        try:
            self.current_expression = str(eval(self.total_expression))

            self.total_expression = ""
        except Exception as e:
            self.current_expression = ("Error")
        finally:
            self.update_label()

    def create_equals_button(self):
        button = tk.Button(self.buttons_frame, text="=", bg= "#CCEDFF", fg= LABEL_COLOR, font= DEFAULT_FONT_STYLE, borderwidth=0,
                             activebackground="#B8E6FF",activeforeground="#111237",command=self.evaluate)
        button.grid(row=4, column=4, columnspan=2, sticky=tk.NSEW)

        def changeeql_on_hovering(event):
          global create_equals_button
          button['bg']="#B8E6FF"


        def returneql_to_normalstate(event):
          global create_equals_button
          button['bg']= "#CCEDFF"
        
        button.bind("<Enter>", changeeql_on_hovering)
        button.bind('<Leave>',returneql_to_normalstate)

  
    def create_buttons_frame(self):
        Frame= tk.Frame(self.window)
        Frame.pack(expand=True, fill="both")
        return Frame
    
    def update_total_label(self):
        expression = self.total_expression
        for operator, symbol in self.operations.items():
            expression = expression.replace(operator, f' {symbol}')
        self.total_label.config(text=expression)

    def update_label(self):   
        self.label.config(text=self.current_expression[:12])
    
    def run(self):
     self.window.mainloop()


Calculator().run()
```

Comment: Well, you already seem to have the nav menu. So what's the problem?

Comment: no i have created a toggle menu differently, but idk how to add a menu like that to the calculator

Comment: Please try to reduce this code down to a [mcve]. If the question is about creating a drop-down menu, we don't need most of the code for the calculator.

Comment: Is there a reason you want custom menu behavior rather than using an actual menu? You can create menus with tkinter that aren't tied to a menubar or right-click.

Comment: @BryanOakley how to create the menu bar?

Comment: Why are you asking how to create a menubar? I thought you wanted a single menu button?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new class for your toggle menu and then, by pressing the button, just call its `place` and `place_forget` method to make it pop-up and hide. Minimally working example is provided below.

```
import tkinter as tk

class ToggleMenu(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent, width=150, height=300, bg='green')
        self.button_callback = None
        # Creating UI
        self.create_text(75, 150, text='Some content', anchor=tk.CENTER, font='TimesNewRoman 16')
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text='Desired button', command=lambda: self.button_callback())
        self.create_window(75, 180, window=self.button)

    def set_button_callback(self, callback):
        self.button_callback = callback

    def ui_start(self):
        self.place(x=0, y=0)
        
    def ui_stop(self):
        self.place_forget()

class App:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.geometry("375x660")
        self.root.resizable(height=True, width= True)
        self.root.title("Calculator")
        # Parameters
        self.is_toggle_active: bool = False
        # Create UI
        self.__ui_create()

    def ui_start(self):
        self.root.mainloop()
        
    def __ui_create(self):
        self.label = tk.Label(self.root, text='This is your calculator', font='TimesNewRoman 16')
        self.label.pack()
        # ... other widgets of your calculator are created and packed\grided here
        # ...
        # ...
        # Should be created exact in this order, othwerwise widgets above will overlap toggle menu and button
        self.toggle_menu = ToggleMenu(self.root)
        self.toggle_menu.set_button_callback(self.__toggle_callback)
        self.button_toggle = tk.Button(self.root, text='Button', command=self.__button_toggle_handler)
        self.button_toggle.place(x=0, y=0)
        
    def __button_toggle_handler(self):
        if self.is_toggle_active:
            self.toggle_menu.ui_stop()
            self.is_toggle_active = False
        else:
            self.toggle_menu.ui_start()
            self.is_toggle_active = True
            
    def __toggle_callback(self):
        print('We succesfully connected togle menu and main window')
        # Do some stuff here
            
 
if __name__.__eq__('__main__'):
    app = App()
    app.ui_start()
```

[Animated gif that demonstrates result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7tuU.gif)

EDIT:
I have added a button as you wished. You can create any UI inside your `ToggleMenu` class. If you need to execute some code that makes changes to your main `App` class, then you can easily connect them via callback as I did.

Comment: i did it in your way but in the part that you have mentioned "Some Content", i need it is as a button. i need like when i click the button on the left corner of the calculator, i need to have a button where you have mentioned "Some Content"..... I'm new to tkinter.... pls help me!!!!!!!!